# Is it possible to change the language from english to other in lstset?

Tags: captions, listings, input-encodings

Generally speaking.
Is it possible to change the language from english to other for captions in lstset?
If yes, how do I do it?

Example of captioned text:

```
 \lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,caption={åäö}]{myfile.m}
```

Error messge is

```
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
```

It can not compile with åäö

Comment: Just redefine `\lstlistingname`, which is `Listing` by defaut.

Comment: That only replaces the name of the listing. I am seeking to change the language for the captioned text.

Comment: Can you provide an example demonstrating what the "captioned text" really is?

Comment: Yes, edited it in

Comment: Still not sure I understand your question. Do you want to use `language=<Matlab in other language>`?

Comment: No that's the coding language of the file I want to insert to my text. The issues arrise with åäö in caption. It can not handle non english letters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109649/discussion-between-muzimuzhi-z-and-asasasasas).

Comment: Looks like a problem with your input encoding

Comment: As @cgnieder already mentions you are probably saving your document in the wrong encoding and presumably have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTF-8 was the issue.

Replacing å, ä, ö with  the characters Ã¥, Ã¤, Ã¶ and Å, Ä, Ö with Ã…, Ã„ ,Ã• solves the issue.

i.e.

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,caption={Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶}]{myfile.m}
```

Comment: That make no sense at all, as already mentioned please provide a full but minimal example.

Comment: This is a clear indication that your overall document encoding is incorrect. Which is why we ask you to provide full examples. A document properly set up for utf8 has no issues with `caption={åäö}`